# Excel Formula to pull numbers

Tags: excel-formula

I need help with a formula that will pull just the first 2-3 numbers in a string

Example:

[image]

In this example the top one I need it to pull just the 30, in the bottom I want to pull just the 106.
The formula I currently have doesn't work well. When the number is 3 digits it only pulls 2 and occasionally it doesn't work at all and gives me some really strange results.

Current Formula I'm using:    `=MID(RC[-3],MIN(IF((ISNUMBER(MID(RC[-3],ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&LEN(RC[-3]))),3)+0)*ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&LEN(RC[-3])))),ISNUMBER(MID(RC[-3],ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&LEN(RC[-3]))),3)+0)*ROW(INDIRECT(""1:""&LEN(RC[-3]))))),3)+0`

Any help or or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With which excel version are you working?

Comment: Can't you use first space, first `-`?

Comment: Will the number you want to pull always start at the 4th character of the string and will its 'end' always be marked by the dash '-' symbol?

Comment: @Ike using excel version 2209. P.b That's a great idea! Dattel Klauber yes! you are exactly correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this formula it doesn't matter what is before your first numbers, but it depends on the delimiter after your first numbers the "-"

```
=LET(firstnum; MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&"0123456789"));delimiter;FIND("-";A2);
MID(A2;firstnum;delimiter-firstnum))
```

if you always have a space before and "-" after your first numbers, you also could this shorter formula:

```
=LET(space;FIND(" ";A2;1);minus;FIND("-";A2;1);
MID(A2;space;minus-space))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm having an issue with your formula. I keep getting an error message that says "The first argument of LET must be a valid name". Not sure why though. I assume the alias firstnum should be fine.

Comment: gotcha! really appreciate your help! Getting a type mismatch when plugging into my formula code. Do you have any idea's? I plugged this into my vba code for a formula.

Comment: @deke then you didn't change the semicolon, which my Excel needs to a comma, which your excel needs

Comment: @deke The type mismatch might be because the variable can't hold that. watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1aJEO1x5G0

Comment: Okay, I did convert the colons to comma's. I'll check out that video and see what I can figure out.